# Filling values based on conditions in 2 columns in R

Tags: r, match

I have a data frame in which I need to fill in values in a column only if 2 conditions, based on 2 other columns, apply.

```
# Generating data
df<- data.frame(date= sample(seq(as.Date('2023/10/01'), as.Date('2024/03/01'), by="day"),50),
                group= sample(LETTERS[1:4],50,replace = T),
                value= rnorm(50),
                label=NA)
```

I need to copy the values in *value* into the *label* column for the latest date of each *group*.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have tried both suggestions in the comments.
`df$label <- ave(1:nrow(df), df$group, FUN = \(i) replace(df$label[i], which.max(df$date[i]), df$value[i][1]))` uses `mean` and does not copy the data correctly.

`df |> mutate(.by = group, label2 = if_else(row_number() == which.max(date), value, label))` gives out an error `` Error in `n()`: ! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`, `filter()`, and `group_by()`. Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred. ``

Comment: Base R: `df$label <- ave(1:nrow(df), df$group, FUN = \(i) replace(df$label[i], which.max(df$date[i]), df$value[i][1]))`

Comment: Dplyr (1.1.0 or newer): `df |> mutate(.by = group, label2 = if_else(row_number() == which.max(date), value, label))`

Comment: if LTyrone's answer and my comments don't work for you, and you can't figure it out with the dupe-links, please [edit] your question to include what you've tried, its output, and why that output is wrong. After that, please @-ping me and we'll sort through the problems to get it resolved. Hope this works for you!

Comment: @r2evans - ooops, thanks for that. Your solution is the go.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans. The Dplyr answer was helpful.